# Warning message: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.2.1

Tags: dplyr

How do I solve this?

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

This warning appears when you load a package that was built under a version of R different to the one you are running.

You have several options:

- Update R to the latest version
- build/compile dplyr with your current version of A
- ignore the warning

If the difference between your R version and the R version where the package was compiled is small (e.g. a patch version change 4.2.0 vs 4.2.1) it is usually fine to ignore the warning.

If you don't want to ignore the warning, updating R and installing/updating the packages again is a solution.

Building the packages yourself is also possible, you would need some specific tools such as Rtools on Windows and some compiler in any system. This is a bit harder so it would not be my first solution to try if you are starting with R.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to install the dplyr package in R4.2.1 and facing this issue.
So you can try this,

In RStudio,
Click on Tools -> install packages.. -> Under packages section type dplyr -> install.